# XSL-FO test the value of <fo:page-number/>

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a .xml file and I would like to generate a .pdf file. I use xsl-fo to make this happen.

The problem is that I cannot request the number of the current page in order to store it into a variable and than make different things depending on its value.

Concrete: if the current page is 0 modulo 3, than I need to draw a "X" at the buttom of the page, if the current page is 1 modulo 3, than I nedd to draw "Y" at the buttom of the page, if the current page is 2 modulo 3, than I nedd to draw "B" at the buttom of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is create different `fo:page-sequence-master`for page position, odd or even pages (usually used to define margins), or blank pages. See [1] for more info.

I can make an example if that helps. But the page number cannot be queried to generate content.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_conditional-page-master-reference

Comment: Ok. Then I need to found something else. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Usually what FO has isn't a problem. A couple of complex master references, along with conditional page-master-reference, can solve most problems.

If your pages are really small, you could create a separate fo:page-sequence for each page and have them use a different master-reference to have different footers... but once your content goes over one page, things will look different.

Comment: Thanks again. I have found a solution using PDFBox. After the PDF file is created I can edit the PDF in order to obtain exactly what I want.  


http://pdfbox.apache.org/